# PyParsing ignores newline?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to parse a git log file that looks like this:

```
d2436fa AuthorName 2015-05-15 Commit Message
4    3    README.md
```

The output I'm expecting looks like this:

```
[ ['d2436fa', 'AuthorName', '2015-05-15', 'Commit Message'],
[4, 3, 'README.md'] ]
```

My grammar to parse this is:

```
hsh = Word(alphanums, exact=7)
author = OneOrMore(Word(alphas + alphas8bit + '.'))
date = Regex('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
message = OneOrMore(Word(printables + alphas8bit))
count = Word(nums)
file = Word(printables)
blankline = LineStart() + LineEnd()

commit = hsh + Combine(author, joinString=' ', adjacent=False) + \
         date + Combine(message, joinString=' ', adjacent=False) + LineEnd()
changes = count + count + file + LineEnd()
check = commit ^ changes ^ blankline
```

The output I actually get is:

```
['d2436fa', 'AuthorName', '2015-05-15', 'Commit Message 4 3 README.md']
```

Why is the newline ignored? I thought that is what LineEnd() is for? When I split over '\n' everything works fine :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyparsing` has a (controversial?) [rule](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing) about whitespace in grammars:

> During the matching process, whitespace between tokens is skipped by default (although this can be changed)

And, as it says, it can be changed. You can set what is considered a whitespace by pp by doing something like the following:

```
i_consider_whitespaces_to_be_only = ' '
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(i_consider_whitespaces_to_be_only)
```

(this will tell it to use only spaces, not newlines; of course, you could also add other stuff, e.g., tabs.)

Comment: Nice answer - I would only add that this is best to add in your code as soon as possible after importing pyparsing, so that your grammar definitions all use the same whitespace character set.

Comment: Oh, @PaulMcGuire himself! Used your package many times. Thanks!